# TemplateBinding with custom class

Tags: wpf, templates

I have a custom class that extends `Control` like so:

```
class TheCountry : Control
{
//...details
}
```

Then I have that element in my XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas" Height="768" Width="1536" AllowDrop="False">
    <spots:TheCountry Country="Australia" Canvas.Left="1362" Canvas.Top="486" Template="{DynamicResource TheCountryIcon}" />
</Canvas>
```

And in my resources I have the template:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TheCountryIcon" TargetType="{x:Type spots:TheCountry}">
        <Grid Width="35" Height="35">
            <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Property=CountryImagePath}" Width="35" Height="35" AllowDrop="True"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and I have the dependancy property called `CountryImagePath` in my `TheCountry` class, but when I run my app, I do not get the image showing up.

I have even put a break point on the getter in the dependancy property, and it does not get hit. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Breakpoints in dependency properties don't actually work - WPF bypasses the getter and setter once the binding is established. Have a look at this post from Bea Stollnitz for some tips for debugging bindings:

[How can I debug WPF bindings?](http://beacosta.com/blog/?p=52)

What you're doing sounds reasonable. Are you certain the "CountryImagePage" is set correctly?

Comment: Yeah Im pretty certain, Ill look into those debugging techniques, thanks